# Burn a HEX file into Brenner8 using linux

Tags: pic, linux, programmer

I have got a version of Brenner8 called AEI when I try to burn my HEX file into 
PIC16f877a using command

```
 usburn -w -s40 -F16 -Ifilename.X.production.hex
```

I got this output

usburn V 0.4 (16.05.2010) by sprut (www.sprut.de)

search for Brenner8/9:   Brenner8 detected, Fw: 15

check firmware

no calibration data

supported:  PIC10F , PIC16F , PIC18F , dsPIC30F , PIC18FxxK ,

Database detected V.24 (06/05/2010)

PIC-Type: unknown

[image: A photo of the programmer]

Comment: I'm going to guess that you have the chip actually inserted when you run it...

Comment: No
I connect it to the laptop then insert the chip

Answer (score 1):

> I got this output...
>
> **no calibration data**

The programmer *must* be calibrated before use, to set the Vpp voltage range. An uncalibrated programmer can produce up to 30V! The chip you tried to program is probably fried, so throw it away and try another one *after* calibrating the programmer.

[Brenner8 Calibration under Linux](http://www.sprut.de/electronic/pic/projekte/brenner8/calibration_under_linux.pdf)

Comment: When I try to calibrate it by using usburn -k it gives the same output 
when I try to run any command from usburn it gives me the same output

Comment: Same as what? Were you able to complete the calibration procedure? Does it still say "no calibration data"?

Comment: I have measured the Z-voltage from the Zener diode and it gives me 3.28 then I connect Brenner8 to Laptop and type in the terminal usburn -k as in the calibration manual but when I press enter it gives me no calibration data

Comment: What did it say when you started the calibration? Did you get to calibration step 3, and what did it say then?

Comment: In the first step when I type usburn -k it gives me no calibration data

Comment: When it says "no calibration data" you need to type + and ENTER several times until the value shown matches the voltage you measured across the Zener (ie. 3.28V).

Comment: So I will keep type usburn -k + until the value matches 3.3 V during this operation it will give me no calibration data and I will keep typing until value matches

Comment: When you run usburn -k it should say "+++ W A R N I G  / W A R N U N G +++ Remove PIC from testsocket and ICSP-connector! press ENTER to continue". After you press ENTER it should then wait for you to enter '+' or '-' (to change the value) and finally '=' to store the calibration voltage.

Comment: No it doesn't give me this ,it gives me the same screen of no calibration data

Comment: Then it is not going into calibration mode. try 'usburn -calibrate'.

Comment: Give me the same

Comment: Sorry, that should be 'usburn --calibration'. If this is not accepted then perhaps the programmer needs a firmware update.

Comment: It doesn't work , How to update firmware , but I use 64bit and installed 32 libraries is it ok?

Comment: 32 bit code should work fine on a 64 machine. Use -f to update firmware. Download firmware from http://www.sprut.de/electronic/pic/projekte/brenner8/index.htm. Hex file 'b8_fw16.hex' is in archive 'b8_fw.zip'.

Comment: I have reinstalled usburn and it works now Thx